# Invalid `Podfile` file: cannot load such file -- ⁨path/to/.ios/Flutter/podhelper.rb

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods

i am trying to integrate flutter module to an existing iOS app

**my pod file :**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'


target 'IosFlutter' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use        dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for IosFlutter

  target 'IosFlutterTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'IosFlutterUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
 end

 flutter_application_path = '⁨⁨path/to/flutter_app⁩/'
 load File.join(flutter_application_path, '.ios', 'Flutter', 'podhelper.rb')

end
```

when running pod install in terminal i got this error :

```
Invalid `Podfile` file: cannot load such file -- path/to/.ios/Flutter/podhelper.rb
```

any advise would be appreciated , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- make sure your flutter and dart version is up to date
- run flutter doctor to see if anything went wrong
- load your flutter file out of target block and add install_all_flutter_pods inside your app dependency block like this :

  ```
  flutter_application_path = '⁨⁨path/to/flutter_app⁩/'
  load File.join(flutter_application_path, '.ios', 'Flutter', 'podhelper.rb')

  target 'MyApp' do

    install_all_flutter_pods(flutter_application_path)

  end
  ```

and finaly run **pod install** in terminal ios app root folder